# Weekday Factor displaying alphabetically

Tags: r

I'm trying to create boxplots using the code below.  I've also included sample data.  It's time-series data, I have a date-time field, and I've created a factor for Weekday.  The problem I have is that my Weekdays when displayed in the boxplot are out of order.  I think it's doing it alphabetically instead of chronologically.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Also I'd like to rotate the x-axis labels like 45 degrees, so they'll all fit, and have them all displayed.

Code:

```
boxplot(OrderCnt ~ Weekday, data=icartdf_factor, main="Orders vs Weekday", xlab="Weekday", ylab="Orders")
```

Sample Data:

```
dput(droplevels(icartdf_factor[1:50,]))
structure(list(OrderCnt = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 
16L, 30L, 27L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 37L, 36L, 35L, 30L, 27L, 17L, 8L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 19L, 28L, 27L, 28L, 
22L, 29L, 41L, 35L, 43L, 42L, 27L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), DateTime = structure(c(1398931200, 1398934800, 1398938400, 
1398942000, 1398945600, 1398949200, 1398952800, 1398956400, 1398960000, 
1398963600, 1398967200, 1398970800, 1398974400, 1398978000, 1398981600, 
1398985200, 1398988800, 1398992400, 1398996000, 1398999600, 1399003200, 
1399006800, 1399010400, 1399014000, 1399017600, 1399021200, 1399024800, 
1399028400, 1399032000, 1399035600, 1399039200, 1399042800, 1399046400, 
1399050000, 1399053600, 1399057200, 1399060800, 1399064400, 1399068000, 
1399071600, 1399075200, 1399078800, 1399082400, 1399086000, 1399089600, 
1399093200, 1399096800, 1399100400, 1399104000, 1399107600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Weekday = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Friday", 
"Saturday", "Thursday"), class = "factor"), hourcol = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("00", "01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("OrderCnt", "DateTime", "Weekday", 
"hourcol"), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify the desired order within the factor itself.

```
icartdf_factor$Weekday = factor(icartdf_factor$Weekday, 
    levels = c("Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))
boxplot(OrderCnt ~ Weekday, data=icartdf_factor, 
    main="Orders vs Weekday", xlab="Weekday", ylab="Orders")
```

[image: Revised Boxplot]

To change the angle of the labels, take a look at [How can I change the angle of the value labels on my axes?](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-change-the-angle-of-the-value-labels-on-my-axes/)